# Hive get rows that exceed average by 10000

Tags: linux, hive, average

I'm trying to use Hive to display the rows in my table that exceeds the average salary (AnnualSalary) of each unique job Role (ROLE) by more that 10000.
I tried using the code below which didn't work and got the error on the bottom

```
hive> SELECT ROLE, AVG(AnnualSalary) From Salaries WHERE AnnualSalary > AVG(AnnualSalary) +10000   GROUP BY ROLE;
```

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10128]: Line 1:66 Not yet supported place for UDAF 'AVG'

Comment: Well, do you plan on discussing what the problem or error is? Or do you plan on keeping it to yourself?

Comment: @jww I put in the error... problem is i cant get the code to run

Answer (score 0):

[Having Clause](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-HAVINGClause)

```
SELECT ROLE, AVG(AnnualSalary) 
FROM Salaries 
GROUP BY ROLE
HAVING AnnualSalary > (AVG(AnnualSalary) + 10000);
```

Comment: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 1:66 Expression not in GROUP BY key '10000'

Comment: Fixed that issue needed to be 'Group by ROLE, AnnualSalary'